# Problem wrapping a Draggable Widget in flutter. I'm attempting to have a draggable widget move to the next Row

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable, wrapper

Attempting to wrap a draggable widget is not formatting properly. I'm attempting to have the Drag Target move to the next row. I'm specifically looking to implement a draggable that takes on a gridview like look. I'm new to flutter and figured the best way to do so was by wrapping my draggable features.

```
body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Draggable<int>(
                data: 10,
                feedback: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  ),
                  height: 50,
                  width: 100,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.directions_run),
                ),
                childWhenDragging: Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  ),
                  child: const Center(),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  ),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('Crawler 1'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Wrap(
                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                  alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
                  spacing: 20,
                  runSpacing: 20,
                  children: [
                    DragTarget<int>(
                      builder: (
                        BuildContext context,
                        List<dynamic> accepted,
                        List<dynamic> rejected,
                      ) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 50.0,
                          width: 100.0,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.deepOrange,
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text('$acceptedData'),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      onAccept: (int data) {
                        setState(() {
                          acceptedData += data;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    DragTarget<int>(
                      builder: (
                        BuildContext context,
                        List<dynamic> accepted,
                        List<dynamic> rejected,
                      ) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 50.0,
                          width: 100.0,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.deepOrange,
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text('$acceptedData'),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      onAccept: (int data) {
                        setState(() {
                          acceptedData += data;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    DragTarget<int>(
                      builder: (
                        BuildContext context,
                        List<dynamic> accepted,
                        List<dynamic> rejected,
                      ) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 50.0,
                          width: 100.0,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.deepOrange,
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text('$acceptedData'),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      onAccept: (int data) {
                        setState(() {
                          acceptedData += data;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ]),
```